# Backbone Collection is populated with models but cannot pull JSON out of it... simple answer I'm sure

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Thank you for all the help this community has given me, I am extremely grateful. If anyone knows what im doing incorrectly I would love to figure this out :)

**The Problem:**
I just started using backbone. lol But really, I am trying building and app that uses full calendar and backbone to populate the calendar. Everything is going smooth so far and I am able to add new sessions with the correct start and end dates to the calendar.

But on the initial load none of these session models populate on the calender. Here is a screenshot of what I am getting in `console.log`:
[image]

As you can see when I call jus the collection you can see it is full of models. But when I try to convert to JSON it comes up empty. I have found numerous answers on Stack Overflow about this and none of them seems to make this work. I am officially roadblocked. lol

Here is some code im working with to display collection

```
  var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
    methodToURL: {
        'create': addDayURL,
        'update': addDayURL,
        //'delete': '/user/remove'
    },
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

        Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }
});

var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: allDaysURL
});
```

The view is huge so I wil only include the relavent parts:

```
 var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #add_track' : "addTrack"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this); 

        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('change', this.change);            
        this.collection.bind('destroy', this.destroy);

        this.eventView = new EventView(); 

        console.log('this.collection: ', this.collection);
        console.log('this.collection.toJSON(): ', this.collection.toJSON());
        console.log('JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()): ', JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()));
        //console.log(this.collection.toJSON())

        // your model2 option: this.options.collection2.toJSON();
        //console.log(this.options.collection2.toJSON());           
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',

            },
            //defaultView: 'resourceDay',
            resources: //this.options.collection2.toJSON()
            [
                {
                    /*
                     * trackID
                     * name
                     * backgroundColor
                     * foregroundColor*/

                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Track 1',
                    color: 'red',
                    textColor: 'black'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Track 2',
                    color: 'blue'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Track 3',
                    color: 'pink'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: 'Track 4',
                    color: 'green'
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'Track 5',
                    color: 'yellow',
                    textColor: 'black'
                }
            ],
            droppable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            ignoreTimezone: false,                
            select: this.select,
            eventClick: this.eventClick,
            eventDrop: this.eventDropOrResize,        
            eventResize: this.eventDropOrResize,
            drop: function(date, allDay, ev, ui, res) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // dropped event of resource a to a cell belonging to resource b?
                copiedEventObject.resourceId = res.id;


                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

                this.addOne;
            }
        });
        this.$el.prepend('<button id="add_track" class="btn large-btn green-btn pull-right">Add Track</button>');
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.collection.toJSON());
    },
    addOne: function(event) {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event.toJSON());
    }
```

**EDIT:**
To initialize collection and populate this code resides at the bottom fo the file:

```
var events = new Events();
var tracks = new Tracks();
new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events, collection2: tracks}).render();
new AddSessionView({ collection: events}).render();
events.fetch();
```

Comment: where do you actually initialize and populate the collection?

Comment: @Evan - Updated, forgot to add that part, it was at the bottom of my file.

Comment: Did you find a solution, this is a problem for me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that `fetch()` was an asynchronous operation, therefore when you fetch a collection, the ajax call will be sent and then your code will continue being run just like nothing happened.

I ended up creating my creating my first view inside the `fetch()` success handler:

```
events.fetch({success: function (models) {
    tracks.fetch({success: function (models) {
        new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events, collection2: tracks}).render();
    }});
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Backbone but maybe this helps. Have you tried to convert the `models` property of your Collection object to JSON, like:

```
JSON.stringify(collection.models)
```

This approach worked for me.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YcFmB/

Comment: No luck, still empty `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

Could be an `async` issue in that `events.fetch();` is returning after your views have been called.  I use deferreds to deal with this.

```
var events = new Events();
var tracks = new Tracks();

$.when( events.fetch() )
.done( function(data) {
  console.dir(data)
  new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events, collection2: tracks}).render();
  new AddSessionView({ collection: events}).render();
});
```

Although, your `bind` on `reset`, should take care of that...

EDIT: 
I would be curious to know what your `console` readout above was?

Comment: unfortunately this didn't do it. i am still get the same readout in my console. I did notice a difference between the data structure of my collection compared to say... http://jsfiddle.net/YcFmB/ Maybe thats the problem, I just don't know why that would be...

Comment: I would be curious to know what your console readout above was?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var events = new Events();
var tracks = new Tracks();

events.fetch();

new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events, collection2: tracks}).render();
new AddSessionView({ collection: events}).render();
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't do it. i am still get the same readout in my console. I did notice a difference between the data structure of my collection compared to say... http://jsfiddle.net/YcFmB/ Maybe thats the problem, I just don't know why that would be...

Comment: i would make your own fetch function. make the ajax call in there and make sure you are adding the data to the collection correctly from your ajax call